# How to reduce latency in Twilio forwarded call?

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio with OpenVBX to forward calls from a US number to an Argentina cell phone.  It works well but there's significant latency in the conversation.  When I use Skype to talk between the US and Argentina there is no latency.

What do I need to learn to get my latency down?  Do I need to find a different carrier than the Twilio default to forward calls from the US to Argentina?  Perhaps route them as SIP first?  I'm not sure where to begin looking.

Answer (score 1):

Rob from Twilio here.

Sorry to hear you're having difficulty with latency forwarding calls from a US number to Argentina.  Would really like to dig into this problem further by having our technicians look at some of the calls in question.

Can you find a few CallSids that exhibited this behavior and send them to help@twilio.com?  You can find your CallSids in the activity log of [your account here](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/calls?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon).  With that information our support team can help troubleshoot what is going on with these latent calls.

Thanks!